# Benefits and drawbacks of using the SNI extensions with SSL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, iis, ssl

We're in the middle of evaluating what the best way to encrypt all our web applications in SharePoint would be.

We have taken into account what different types of certificates there are and their pros and cons, what services and other functions that is necessary for us to have and what type of changes we have to do to our current infrastructure.

One thing is recently stumbled over **Server Name Indication** (SNI) and i'm now looking into if this could work for us. [Server Name Indication - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)

The pros that i could found is the following:

1. Using one single IP/port for all the web applications and no need to assign unique IP-addresses or non default ports. (As long as you are using Host-Headers of course)
2. The ability to use single certificates for every web application and thus increasing security instead of using a [wildcard certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) or a [SAN certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubjectAltName) that would need to be updated if we wish to add another web application in the future.

The cons that i have found is this:

1. The WebDAV protocol does **not** support SNI, and therefore make "Open in Explorer" in SharePoint rather useless. The same goes to mapping a drive as this use the same protocol.
2. The IIS Module [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) seem to **not** support SNI either. This can be a pretty important function to some organisations. [SharePoint, SNI, and HTTP Redirect Issues](http://stephkdonahue.com/sharepoint-sni-and-http-redirect-issues/)

Are there anything else i should be aware about? How does Office Web Apps works with SNI?

Could there be any problems when using SharePoint Apps on a different domain? Or having a "[Listener](http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/adawson/post/2014/08/15/Configuring-SharePoint-2013-Apps-and-Multiple-Web-Applications-on-SSL-with-a-Single-IP-Address.aspx)" web application with no host header that receives the apps traffic?